# How to make transition effect for welcoming message in php after signing in?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I have this code to set the cookie on a website :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name])){
     echo '<html><head></head><body></br></br></br><h1><center>Hello, '.$_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name].'! Welcome back!</center></h1></body></html>';
     sleep(2);
     header('Location: ../index.php');   
    }                         
   else if (setcookie( $_first_name.$_last_name, $_first_name.' '.$_last_name, time() + 60*60*24*5))
   ;
```

The first time it will register the name, the second time, it won't give me the welcoming message and will direct me instantly to the home page. I want it to wait for 2 second for the user to see the welcome message and then auto direct the user to the home page.

**More INFO**

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ERROR);
session_start();
include('loginScript.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
}
?>
<html> 
...
...
</html>
```

in the above code, I'm calling the loginScript.php which contains the code to check for cookies.

### section from the loginScript.php file

```
  if ($rows == 1) {
         $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
         // $_SESSION['items'][] =$username;
         $_SESSION['firstname'] =$result['Firstname'];
        $_first_name = $_SESSION['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] =$result['Lastname'];
        $_last_name = $_SESSION['lastname'];

    if (isset($_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name])){
         echo '<html><head></head><body></br></br></br><h1><center>Hello, 
    '.$_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name].'! Welcome back!</center></h1></body> 
    </html>';
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        //sleep(2);
        echo "<script>setTimeout(()=> 
      {document.location.href='index.php'},2000);</script>";  
                                    }                         
      else if (setcookie( $_first_name.$_last_name, $_first_name.' 
       '.$_last_name, time() + 60*60*24*5)){
        // Code of rest of the entire login page
       }
      } 
else {
   $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
   }
   mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
```

Comment: Do the transition effect over css3 and send the form over Ajax (JS) to the server and create an redirect with JS to the new page after the success full "login".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can't `sleep` on an output without flushing in php. You will have to call

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

in order to force php to output the contents before sleeping and performing the rest of the code.

Secondly, you cannot output anything before changing headers - in your case, setting the location header. A simple workaround is to use javascript to redirect the page instead. So you will have something like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name])){
     echo '<html><head></head><body></br></br></br><h1><center>Hello, '.$_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name].'! Welcome back!</center></h1></body></html>';
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     sleep(2);
     echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php'</script>";  
     die(); //added to prevent the rest of the output
    }                         
   else if (setcookie( $_first_name.$_last_name, $_first_name.' '.$_last_name, time() + 60*60*24*5))
   ;
```

However, it is often not advisable to use `sleep` unless absolutely necessary, as `sleep` uses your server resources and imagine if everyone is `sleep`ing and that is a waste of your resources and stopping the server from handling new requests.

We can workaround this further by offloading this delay to the client side using javascript `settimeout`.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name])){
     echo '<html><head></head><body></br></br></br><h1><center>Hello, '.$_COOKIE[$_first_name.$_last_name].'! Welcome back!</center></h1></body></html>';
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     //sleep(2);
     echo "<script>setTimeout(()=>{document.location.href='index.php'},2000);</script>";  
    }                         
   else if (setcookie( $_first_name.$_last_name, $_first_name.' '.$_last_name, time() + 60*60*24*5)){
// Code of rest of the entire login page
}
```

Last but not least, as Richard mentioned in the comments, it is actually a better practice to handle this all from the client side, then you will also have more control over transitions, etc etc. That will be out of the scope of this question, but you can consider redesigning the program flow as what he suggested. Otherwise, the above workarounds should do find to achieve your needs.

Comment: I have two problems, the first one, if I use the second code, after it shows the welcome message it will direct me back to the login page first, and then to the home page. But I don' t want the login page.

The second problem is, if I use the first code, it will work, it won't show me the login page, and will show the home page directly, however, it won't wait for 2 seconds, I changed that to 4 as well, but it direct me very fast. It doens't seem that it's sleeping, it only shows the welcome message for a fraction of second.

Comment: Yes. `flush` is also server dependent, check out documentation here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php. that's why the first method is not advisable. As for the second method, why won't you want it display the login page? Is it because there are other output further below the page? If you wrap the login page output in the `else if(setcookie..)` then you won't see the rest of the login page so it makes no difference which page the welcome note is on. I have edited the answer to show where you can add the code.

Comment: I just edited the post. Can you check the more info section above? because I'm calling the setcookies from another php file, and also, the setcookies is embedded in another if statement, I also showed that.

Comment: just edited. add a `die();` to exit the rest of your script and not output them. Not the best practice, but it is often used anyway, just be sure you completed all your tasks and close all you need to close.